# Simplified syntax for cms

Tags: php, user-interface

I'm providing a small php + mysql CMS for a website that will be update by the owner.
As seen onto WordPress, I'd like to give user the opportunity to make more complex updates by using a syntax like this:

```
[row h="100"]
    [col link="/some/link/1"][/col]
    [col link="/some/link/2"][/col]
    [col link="/some/link/3"][/col]
[/row]

[el id="some-id"][/el]
```

Obviously my CMS has to read and translate this script in normal full html.
For sure I can do it with a lot of replace() written in correct order but I guess that better and more solid way exists.

What do you suggest? How is this kind of syntax named?

Comment: Nothing yet. As I've written, I theorize that I can manage it by many str_replace() but it doesn't seem the best way to me.

Answer (score 0):

Adapt this to your needs

```
function bbc2html($content) {
    $search = array (
        '/(\[b\])(.*?)(\[\/b\])/',
        '/(\[i\])(.*?)(\[\/i\])/',
        '/(\[u\])(.*?)(\[\/u\])/',
        '/(\[ul\])(.*?)(\[\/ul\])/',
        '/(\[li\])(.*?)(\[\/li\])/',
        '/(\[url=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/url\])/',
        '/(\[row h=\")(.*?)(\\"])(.*?)(\[\/row\])/',
        '/(\[col link=\")(.*?)(\\"])(.*?)(\[\/col\])/'
    );

    $replace = array (
        '<strong>$2</strong>',
        '<em>$2</em>',
        '<u>$2</u>',
        '<ul>$2</ul>',
        '<li>$2</li>',
        '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$4</a>',
        '<div class="row" style="height: $2px;">$4</div>',
        '<a class="column" href="$2">$4</a>'
    );

     return preg_replace($search, $replace, $content);
}

echo bbc2html('[row h="100"][col link="/some/link/1"]test 1[/col][col link="/some/link/2"]test 2[/col][col link="/some/link/3"]test 3[/col][/row][el id="some-id"][/el]');
```

Provide a string without spaces to bbc2html()

Comment: Cool system! Thank you hLover.